# What do we call these burn bandages?

Tags: word-request

[image]

I see two types of bandages used, but I am talking about the one on the hands, that can also be applied on other parts of the body. I am not sure what's the other white thing on top of it, and what it's called, but I was looking for the word for the bandage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's **gauze**:

> When used as a medical dressing, woven gauze is usually made of cotton. It is especially useful for dressing wounds where other fabrics might stick to the burn or laceration. — [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauze)

[image: roll and some of its uses: wound dressing, trauma nursing, fixed dressing, fixed joint]

Image from eBay [5 Rolls Gauze Bandage Disposable Leg Ankle Wound Bandages Breathable Soft](https://www.ebay.com/itm/353102510864)

Bonus: The part on top is apparently a [mesh bandage](https://medicom.com/product/tubular-mesh-band/), used to hold other dressings in place. I have never heard of them before but the name is intuitive enough.